# Histogram with ggplot2 that gets data from read.table

Tags: r

When I try to plot a histogram whit data from "read.table" I just get a big square. My measurements are heights of seven students.

[image]

```
# Library
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

# Read data (comma separated)
res = read.table(text = "184,180,183,184,184,160,173", 
               sep=",",stringsAsFactors=F, na.strings="unknown")


# Print table
print(res)
number_of_x <- length(res)
print(number_of_x)

# Plot histogram
ggplot(res, aes(x=number_of_x)) +
    geom_histogram(alpha=0.6, position = 'identity') +
    theme_classic()
```

This gives output:

```
##    V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7
## 1 184 180 183 184 184 160 173


## [1] 7
```

Comment: Your ggplot call is for a histogram of x = 7 (:= number_of_x) ... and this value (x=7) is found/counted a single time. This is what the block shows (centered on x = 7, and height = 1). Ronak below shows how to turn this into a histogram (= listing of counts). From your `position = "identity"` I am not sure, if you do not want to plot a "barchart". For identity bars, you can also use `geom_col()`: df <- data.frame(x = c("V1","V2","V3","V4","V5","V6","V7"), heights = c(184,180,183,184,184,160,173); ggplot(data = df,, aes(x = x, y = heights) + geom_col()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ggplot2` likes data in long format. Also try not to create individual vectors out of the dataframe (like `number_of_x`) unless necessary. You can refer to column values within ggplot code.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


res %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=value)) +
  geom_histogram(alpha=0.6, position = 'identity') +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Error in res %>% pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>% ggplot(aes(x=value))
Could not find function "%>%"

Comment: You'll need `library(dplyr)` for `%>%` and `library(tidyr)` for `pivot_longer()`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `gather`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
res %>%
  gather %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=value)) +
  geom_histogram(alpha=0.6, position = 'identity') +
  theme_classic()
```